# How compute the Intra-Class Correlation for a Negative Binomial Mixed Model in lme4

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, intraclass-correlation

I have a negative binomial mixed model with counties nested within states.
I've read that the formula for the ICC for a negative binomial model is:

[image]
found here: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3916583/

When I run `VarCorr(m10)`, on my random intercept model, I get:
`Groups Name        Std.Dev.
 state  (Intercept) 0.22709`

Could someone explain how to extract the other information from my `glmer()` model so that I can write a function to compute the ICC?
e.g., `fixef(m10)` gets me the intercept term.

Comment: It seems that in your model you did not estimate several of the terms that are referenced in the ICC equation. The equation refers to several different variance components but you only have a single random intercept term.

Answer (score 2):

This is my functional code (using `glmer.nb()`):

```
ICC.NB <- function(model){
  sigma_a2 <- as.numeric(exp(data.frame(VarCorr(model))["vcov"]))
  beta <- as.numeric(fixef(model)["(Intercept)"])
  r <- getME(model,"glmer.nb.theta")
  icc <- (exp(sigma_a2) - 1) / ((exp(sigma_a2) - 1) + ((exp(sigma_a2) - 1) / r) + (exp(-beta - (sigma_a2 / 2))))
  icc
}
ICC.NB(model = m12)
```

Comment: I think there are some ways to make this less fragile and more readable, e.g. use `["vcov"]` in place of `[4]` in the sigma extraction; use `"(Intercept)"` instead of `[1]` to get the intercept; use `getME(model,"glmer.nb.theta"))` instead of the big ugly `gsub` call ...

Comment: @BenBolker , I edited the post and implemented your suggested changes. Thank you.

Comment: don't forget to test them ... :-)

Comment: PS I think the `as.numeric()`s are unnecessary?

Comment: Good idea. Now, I'm trying to add a "var" parameter to make it work with a three level model by setting what the sigma should be.

Comment: a) I wondered if the "exp" in "sigma_a2" is required? b) I have been trying getME(model,"glmer.nb.theta")), but no success even after updating lme4?

Comment: @Hassan, you should give more details/post an issue.